# Bash pipe barrier

Tags: bash, shell, signals

For an assignment, I have to code a script with the following behaviour in bash:

- read linewise text from stdin and store that in a buffer
- when receiving a SIGUSR1 signal, flush the buffer
- when the script shuts down, flush again

shutdown happens when: 
-stdin gets closed
-the script receives either the signals INT or TERM

I figured this:

```
echo "#!/bin/bash
buffer=""
while read line
do
  buffer="${buffer}line"
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"" >>pipe-barrier.sh
```

out on my own. How do I achieve the rest of it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the outer `echo` for? Have a look at `man trap` to read more about traps, which are used to handle signals.

Comment: `help trap` would be more useful the using `man` - although it depends on the system, `man trap` might not tell you much. (`trap` is a shell builtin)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that?

```
#!/bin/bash

trap flush_buffer EXIT TERM INT

flush_buffer() {
    [ -n "$buffer" ] && echo -e "$buffer"
    buffer=""
}    

while read -r line; do
    [ -z "$buffer" ] && buffer="$line" || buffer="$buffer\n$line"
done
```

The script react on Ctrl-D, Ctrl-C and SIGUSR1